# Display next row in adjacent <td> not pagination

Tags: php, pdo

```
$MR = $mt->query('select dated, time1 from det where cus="name 10" and dated between "10-06-2017" and "20-06-2017" order by dated asc');
$MR -> execute();
$result = $MR -> fetchAll();

$i=1;
if ($i%2) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
                    echo $i;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
                    echo $row['dated'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
                    echo $row['time1'];
                echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
                     echo $i;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
                    echo $row['dated'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
                    echo $row['time1'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }


        $i++;
    }
```

I did a fetchAll() using PDO and my table looks like below after doing a $i%2 where $i is the counter.

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| no      | date     | time 1      | time 2     |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 1       |12-06-2017| 05:00       |            |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|         |12-06-2017|             | 11:35      |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 3       |13-06-2017| 04:4        |            |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|         |13-06-2017|             | 13:25      |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

How do I get the value **11:35** adjacent to **05:00** and likewise for other rows.  There are over a 100 rows.  Could I display the next record for time1?

Pagination is not something I am looking for.

[UPDATE]

**Expected Output**

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| no      | date     | time 1      | time 2     |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 1       |12-06-2017| 05:00       | 11:35      |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 2       |13-06-2017| 04:4        |  13:25     |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Post here your expected o/p .

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo Pls check updated Q

Comment: Show the code used to iterate and print the actual output.

Comment: @Saleiro pls check updated Q

Comment: Ok, but there are some code missing... you are using the `$row` var but it where is it declared? Where is the iteration (`foreach`, `while`, etc)?

Comment: @Saleiro You know there is a for each() loop .. can we just omit the obvious :)

Comment: The obvious to you can be a bug to me. ;-) The code shows exactly what you pretend to do (and shows to me what are you really doing). Sorry, cannot help this way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
select dated,
Group_concat( time1 separator ',') as time1
from det 
where 
cus="name 10" and 
dated between "10-06-2017" and "20-06-2017"
group by dated
order by dated asc
```

It will give out put as

```
dated      | time1
12-06-2017 | 05:00,11:35
```

**Edit:-**
use this code to create table rows

```
$times=explode(',', $row['time1']);
$time1=(isset($times[0]))?$times[0]:'';
$time2=(isset($times[1]))?$times[1]:'';
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
echo $i;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
echo $row['dated'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td style='width:20%'>";
echo $row['time1'];
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: @X10nD try the above answer.

Comment: Looking into it now

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' d1.dated=d2.dated

Sorry a little confused but Where did you get time2 from?

Comment: you column name for `time 2 `

Comment: The <th> says time2 but in the db-table col there is only time1

Comment: then how you get time2

Comment: DB is as shown as in SQL query.  Table header is how we write.  Now there are two time entries for a single date.  The first time is time1 and the second time is time2.

Comment: Try the modified answer

Comment: I actually need it as..
dated      | time1 | time 2
12-06-2017 | 05:00 | 11:35

Comment: @bibhuudatta It did not work out for me as you wrote for some reason. I  used CSS to get the records to the above table cell.

Awarded the right answer for your effort!!! thanks!!